# ansible access results and file paths in nested loop

Tags: ansible

I am working on small playbook that will search for files in specified directories and then delete them if they met certain conditions. I have following playbook so far

```
- hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: find logs
      find:
        paths: "{{ item.0 }}"
        file_type: file
        patterns: "{{ item.1 }}"
      register: find_logs
      with_nested:
        - ["/var/log/apache2", "/var/log/nginx"]
        - ["access.log", "error.log"]

    - debug:
        var: item
      loop:
        - "{{ find_logs }}"
```

So this will obviously look into **/var/log/apache2** and **/var/log/nginx** directories and search for *access.log* and *error.log* files. Now, following [ansible's documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) I want to access `files` return values and their paths. The issue I'm having right now is with nested loop and registered `find_logs` variable which holds list of dictionaries in `results` key. If I do `find_logs.results` then I will get a list of dictionaries and each of these dictionaries will have another list of files kept in `files` section. How can I 'flatten' this list even more to be able to retrieve `files.path` for every element produced by nested loop? To be honest I also tried `find_logs | json_query('results[*].files[*]')` but that gives me another list and I can't seem to iterate over it to get what I want (which is path of file). Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I completely misunderstood documentation for `find` module, Nested loop can be excluded in this case and replaced with following syntax

```
- hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: find logs
      find:
        paths:
            - /var/log/apache2
            - /var/log/nginx
        file_type: file
        patterns:
            - "access.log"
            - "error.log"
            - "other_vhosts_access.log"
      register: find_logs

    - name: check what was registered
      debug:
        msg: "my path -> {{ item.path }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ find_logs.files }}"
```